# how to use emojis in my project in Xcode and declare them in a dictionary array?

Tags: swift, dictionary, uikit

simply I have a uiimage and want to use one of the emojis in that . how can I get some of these emojis and place into my project? this is the place I ll get them from.

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166

one more question . next to my uiimage I have a uilabel for currency codes. so to use the image along with the corresponding code  do I need to use a dictionary  like :

```
var dict = ["EUR": "imagenameinString"]
```

or

```
var dict = ["code" : "EUR", "image": "imagenameinString"
```

i want to call the currency code and related image/emoji together. This is my code below using a string value for emoji but I get error in this way naturally. how do I edit this code to work? Thank you!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var amountText: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var amountText2: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var fromLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var fromImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var toImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var toLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    
    let flag = "\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1EA}"
    var currencyManager = CurrencyManager()
    
    
    var from: String = "EUR"
    var to: String = "TRY"
    var amount: String = "0"
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        amountText.delegate = self
        currencyManager.delegate = self
        fromImage.image = flag
        
    }
```

Comment: i understand now. what about my other question? I have 10 currencies in my project which is a currency converter. so  I want to relate each currency code to a specific flag. so for this I need to use dictionary or enum or something else? and can I see an example usage of two codes with two flags? btw I placed a uiimage in the storyboard and I want to change it in place but when I want to assign a string value now to that I get this error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?'"

Comment: but as I said I get an error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?'". Lets say I don't need uiimage but just the string value. so I use storyboard. Which library item I need to use instead of uiimage? because the flag has a place inside the screen and I want to change that part.

Comment: I think I solved it. instead of uiimage I need to use uilabel but now I have to solve the problem of calling them when I click a particular currency it needs to show both the currency and related flag at the same time.